# select from a table depending on 2 other relations

Tags: mysql, sql, join

so ... here we are ... it's not a simple question so first read it carefully please ...

these are my tables

[image: courses]

[image: instructor]

[image: teaches]

- the first image is `courses` table
- the second is `instructors` table
- the third one is `teaches` table

now i want the names of the `instructors` who are `teaching` some `courses` that have 4 credits

i tried this :

```
SELECT *
FROM teaches
INNER JOIN course ON ( course.course_id = teaches.course_id
AND course.credits =4 )
```

but it's not complete yet ... i know which courses have 4 credits but i don't know how to make a relation between this query and the table called instructors

Comment: Maybe isnt simple because you are still studying this and should ask your teacher?

Comment: actually ... no ... because the teacher gave us this question in the exam and no-one could write the answer !! i worked with sql many times but this is not really a simple query to use !

Comment: Can you pls share with us how you tried to write the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT i.name
FROM instructor I
JOIN teaches T
  ON I.ID = T.ID
JOIN courses C
  ON C.course_id = T.course_id
WHERE C.credits = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option in simple way...

```
select * from instructors 
  where id in ( select distinct id 
                from teaches 
                where course_id in ( select distinct course_id 
                                     from courses 
                                     where credits = 4 
                                   )
             );
```